# While Uploading File in ASP.NET , Maximum Request Lenght Exceed

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am using following code to save product images. When I upload 5 images, It runs fine but when I upload 6 images, it gives me exception of **Maximum Request Length Exceed**

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender,EventArgs e) 
   {
       string filepath = Server.MapPath("UploadFiles");
       HttpFileCollection uploadedFiles = Request.Files;
       Span1.Text = string.Empty;

       for(int i = 0;i < uploadedFiles.Count;i++) 
       {
            HttpPostedFile userPostedFile = uploadedFiles[i];

            try 
            {
                if (userPostedFile.ContentLength > 0) 
                {
                    Span1.Text += "File Content Type: " +  userPostedFile.ContentType      + "<br>";
                    Span1.Text += "File Size: " +              userPostedFile.ContentLength           + "kb<br>";
                    Span1.Text += "File Name: " + userPostedFile.FileName + "<br>";

                    userPostedFile.SaveAs(filepath + "\\" +    Path.GetFileName(userPostedFile.FileName));                  
                    Span1.Text += "Location where saved: " +   filepath + "\\" +   Path.GetFileName(userPostedFile.FileName) + "<p>";
                }
            } 
            catch(Exception Ex) 
                {
                    Span1.Text += "Error: <br>" + Ex.Message;
                }
      }
}
```

I did not make any changes in web.config also. can any body guid me where can i change the maximum request length exceed limit. 
***I googled it but did not find the answer.*** Thanx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to set in `web.config` using [httpRuntime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e1f13641%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) tag

```
<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="1048576" />
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

#### maxRequestLength

> Optional Int32 attribute. Specifies the limit for the input stream
>   buffering threshold, in KB. This limit can be used to prevent denial
>   of service attacks that are caused, for example, by users posting
>   large files to the server. The default is 4096 (4 MB), [reference.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e1f13641%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: thnx. can you please refer me some documentation so i can explore it more. :)

Comment: Check it here, I added in my answer as well. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e1f13641(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Adil, Thnxx a lot.. after you answer and refered documentation, I came to know that it doest not depend upon the number of files/images we are uploading, infact it depends the size of file/images being uploading. Thanx once again. :)